# How can I show this equality for the inner product of two bandpass signals?

Tags: digital-communications, signal-energy

Given the real bandpass signals $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ with center frequency $f_0$ and lowpass equivalents $x_l(t)$ and $y_l(t)$ respectively, I want to show that
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty x(t)y(t) \ dt= \frac{1}{2} \text{Re}\left[\int_{-\infty}^\infty x_l(t)y_l^*(t) \ dt \right]
$$
but I am stuck in the following derivation. Using Parseval's theorem,
\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty x(t)y^*(t) \text{d}t &= \int_{-\infty}^\infty X(f)Y^*(f) \ \text{d}f \end{align}
and since $y(t)$ is real,
\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty X(f)Y^*(f) \ \text{d}f &= \int_{-\infty}^\infty X(f)Y(-f) \ \text{d}f \\
&= \int_{-\infty}^\infty \left[ \frac{1}{2}\left(X_l(f - f_0) + X_l^*(-f - f_0)\right) \right]\left[ \frac{1}{2}\left(Y_l(-f - f_0) + Y_l^*(f - f_0)\right) \right] \ \text{d}f \\
&= \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{4}X_l(f - f_0)Y_l(-f - f_0) + \frac{1}{4}X_l^*(-f - f_0) Y_l(-f - f_0) ~+ \\ &\frac{1}{4}X_l(f - f_0)Y_l^*(f - f_0) + \frac{1}{4}X_l^*(-f - f_0)Y_l^*(f - f_0) \ \text{d}f \\
&= \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{4}X_l^*(-f - f_0) Y_l(-f - f_0) + \frac{1}{4}X_l(f - f_0)Y_l^*(f - f_0) \ \text{d}f \\
&= \frac{1}{4} \int_{-\infty}^\infty X_l^*(-f - f_0) Y_l(-f - f_0) + \frac{1}{4} \int_{-\infty}^\infty X_l(f - f_0)Y_l^*(f - f_0) \ \text{d}f
\end{align}
I'm not sure what do after this, so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The product $x(t)y(t)$ can be written as

$$\begin{align}x(t)y(t)&=\textrm{Re}\left\{x_l(t)e^{j2\pi f_ct}\right\}\textrm{Re}\left\{y_l(t)e^{j2\pi f_ct}\right\}\\&=\textrm{Re}\left\{x_l(t)e^{j2\pi f_ct}\right\}\frac12\big[y_l(t)e^{j2\pi f_ct}+y_l^*(t)e^{-j2\pi f_ct}\big]\\&=\frac12\textrm{Re}\left\{x_l(t)y_l^*(t)+x_l(t)y_l(t)e^{j4\pi f_ct}\right\}\tag{1}\end{align}$$

Integrating over $(1)$ gives

$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x(t)y(t)dt=\frac12\textrm{Re}\left\{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x_l(t)y_l^*(t)dt\right\}+\frac12\textrm{Re}\left\{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x_l(t)y_l(t)e^{j4\pi f_ct}dt\right\}\tag{2}
$$

The last term in $(2)$ is the Fourier transform of $x_l(t)y_l(t)$ evaluated at $-2f_c$. Since $x_l(t)$ and $y_l(t)$ are lowpass signals, that term vanishes and the result follows.

Comment: (+1) great answer. Much simpler than my approach. Just one question: could I have concluded after the last line in my derivation that, because the inner product is conjugate symmetric and invariant to frequency reversal and shifting, then...

Comment: ...$$\begin{align} \int_{-\infty}^\infty X(f)Y^*(f) \ \text{d}f &= \frac{1}{4} \int_{-\infty}^\infty X_l^*(-f - f_0) Y_l(-f - f_0) \ \text{d}f + \frac{1}{4} \int_{-\infty}^\infty X_l(f - f_0)Y_l^*(f - f_0) \ \text{d}f \\ &= \frac{1}{4} \left[\int_{-\infty}^\infty X_l(f - f_0)Y_l^*(f - f_0) \ \text{d}f\right]^* + \frac{1}{4} \int_{-\infty}^\infty X_l(f - f_0)Y_l^*(f - f_0) \ \text{d}f \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \text{Re}\left[\int_{-\infty}^\infty X_l(f - f_0) Y_l^*(f - f_0) \ \text{d}f\right] \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \text{Re}\left[\int_{-\infty}^\infty x_l(t) y_l^*(t) \ \text{d}t\right]
\end{align}$$?